# Why do I have to download some python libraries before pip installing them?

Tags: python, packages, libraries, pip

It is possible to install most python libraries like numpy, sklearn, pandas by "pip-installing" them, i.e.

```
pip install numpy
```

However, other libraries like tensorflow, keras and opencv I need to download another file first and then use pip to install them, like:

```
sudo pacman -S python-tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
```

Why is this?

Comment: Because you have two package managers, `pacman` for your Linux distro on the one side and `pip` on the other side. Both work individually and don't cooperate.

Comment: @Robert I know that. You misunderstood my question. What is special about e.g. tensorflow, keras and opencv that I need to do anything other than pip installing?

Comment: I don't think there is something special. It is just your decision to install them via pacman instead of pip. The only advantage I can see in using pacman is that potentially these packages have non-Python requirements which therefore can not be provided by pip.

Comment: @Robert It was not my decision. Installing only using pip for these packages will not work. Okay "non-python requirements" that's what I wanted to know. Like special C-code for efficiency?

Comment: Usually if a python package is well designed and you have the necessary build tools installed pip can build the native libraries upon installation. Not sure how it is on Arch Linux.